# How could I fix this side effect?

Tags: java, loops, statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I am having a problem with the code below; the issue is that after you don't say map the first time, it keeps repeating `No try again` with the input box, no matter if you type "map" or not.

```
 System.out.println("My cousin Diego is in trouble in the Majestic palace. But how do we get there?");
 System.out.println("Who do we call when we don't know where to go?         Huh? I didn't get that...");
 imTheMap=robotMagic.next();
 if (imTheMap.equals("map"))
 {
    System.out.println("That's right!"); //the issue is here
 }
 else 
 {
    while(imTheMap!=("map"))
    {
        System.out.println("No! try again");
        imTheMap=robotMagic.next();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Formatted code would be easier to read!

Comment: To help format the code, try implementing a do{ }while() loop. Grab the robotMagic, and if you escape the loop congratulate the user

Answer (score 6):

By changing

```
 while(imTheMap!=("map"))
```

to

```
 while(!imTheMap.equals("map"))
```

you always should use equals() method to check string equality. as in your if statement.